# Read the value entered in text box in html form and use it by retrieving it in a php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
       <!DOCTYPE>
       <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>  
            <h2>Train Information from Indian Railways API</h2>

            <form id="info">
                Please enter train number:<br><br>
                <input type="text" id="trainno" name="train">
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

            <script>
            $("#info").submit(function(){

              $.ajax({            
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'example.php',             
                    success: function(Result){
                    var myObj = $.parseJSON(Result);
                        console.log(myObj.result);
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        alert('ERROR');
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </body>


    </html>
```

### example.php

```
    <?php

    echo "Value entered is: " .$_GET['train '];

    $ch = curl_init("http://api.erail.in/route/?key=3d970b43-550b-4568-9227-492697f47093&trainno=12138");
    $fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

    //$ch is a cURL handle returned by curl_init

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    //Execute $ch
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //Read the file contents
    $json_data = file_get_contents('example_homepage.txt');
    echo $json_data;
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    ?>
```

I am unable to retrieve the user entered value in php and then use it to manipulate the url there, which gets me the data from API server. When I run the HTML page, it just gives me an alert of ERROR. What am I doing wrong? Is it the ajax call? Should it be post method? I tried using ajaxForm from AJAX plugin but no change. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: please post example.php code

Comment: everything looks great on your html/js code. Provide example.php code, so we can help you with it

Comment: give code snippet of example.php code.

Comment: if you submit the form it will refresh the page. Please try my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the trainno value in the ajax request using "data":

```
$.ajax({            
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'example.php',
    data: { train: $('#trainno').val() },
    success: function(Result){
        var myObj = $.parseJSON(Result);
        console.log(myObj.result);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Train Information from Indian Railways API</h2>

<div style="float:left;">Your train name is: <span style="font-weight: bold" id="holder-name"></span></div>
<br><br>
Please enter train number:<br><br>

<form id="myform" name="myform"></form>
<input type="text" name="train" id="trainno">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save">
</form>

<script>
    $('#save').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "example.php",
            data: {train: $('#trainno').val()},
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data.result.name);
                $('#holder-name').html(data.result.name);
                // YOU CAN DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH THE DATA
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

example.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['train'])){
    $url = 'http://api.erail.in/route/?key=3d970b43-550b-4568-9227-492697f47093&trainno=' . $_REQUEST['train'];
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $data;
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "no data"));
}
```

Comment: Hi Lea, your solution works, thanks! But just wondering, was my example.php visible in my posted question. I did post it with a new heading. Also, what if I want my input field to be in a form and ajax gets executed on submission of form. What was the reason that in your solution you removed form tags? Also, what is the need to set header in php file. I did parse the returned json in ajax call, but it was after adding that form, that everything went haywire. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: I removed the form tag, this way I am preventing the form from submit. instead I added a listener that will trigger when you click the button. This will set a ajax call and the page will not refresh. I always set header when I am working with json, since I had an issue long time ago where my code was treat it as plain text

Comment: Hello Lea, can't prevent default do that? Not sure how to make it work though.

Comment: I guess you right. I willl edit my answer with `prevenDefault()` and the `<form>` tag